# How to properly update a model on laravel? Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I made a page for a user to update his company information, all companies default values are null, when a user is created. When a user fills the information, i get this error:

```
 Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist
```

I am sure this error is because of my CompanyController@edit

```
     public function edit(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'company_name' => 'alpha|max:50',
        'phone' => 'integer|max:50',
        'gst_hst_number' => 'integer|max:50',
        'country' => 'alpha|max:50',
    ]);

    $companies = Company::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    $companies->update([
        'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
        'phone' => $request->input('phone'),
        'gst_hst_number' => $request->input('gst_hst_number'),
        'country' => $request->input('country')
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('company.index')->with('info', 'Company information was updated.');
}
```

I am stuck quite some time on this issue, would gladly apriciate help and information how to properly update my company models fillable fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

‌As the error message says, you are using the update method on a `collection`, you have to change the select query to this:

```
$companies = Company::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

Because the `get()` method returns a collection, not a single record.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Really thankful for your help. :)

Comment: This will need to execute two queries, but will also trigger model events. You can use `update` directly without retrieving the model first to only run one query but that will not trigger model events.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. `->get()` is for multiple collections here you can directly update your records.

```
$companies = Company::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update([
    'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
    'phone' => $request->input('phone'),
    'gst_hst_number' => $request->input('gst_hst_number'),
    'country' => $request->input('country')
]);;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using `update` method on collection, but collection doesn't have `update` method,

what you need is remove the `get()`, so you can use `update` method on eloquent builder:

```php
$companies = Company::where('id', Auth::user()->id);
$companies->update([
        'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
        'phone' => $request->input('phone'),
        'gst_hst_number' => $request->input('gst_hst_number'),
        'country' => $request->input('country')
]);
```